# How to identify the owner of an organization in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I have access to the organization and I'm trying to add someone as owner but system prompts message:
"**You are missing at least one of the following required permissions:**"

Question is how can I know who the owner of this organization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**By design it's not possible to check who's organisation owner** (due to security risks).

If you don't have a proper permissions just ask your IT department / superiors - someone has a required permissions ([Organization Administrator](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/quickstart-organizations#grant_roles_at_the_organization_level)) and will be able to [assign required role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#resource-manager-roles) to your account for you to be able to add another users.